# Como posso mostrar um valor em uma jTextField ao selecionar uma JCheckBox em tempo de execução?

Tags: java, checkbox, textbox

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private void btCalcularActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    double salario = 0, irrf = 0, inss = 0, valorTotal = 0;

    FolhaPagamento pagamento = new FolhaPagamento(Double.parseDouble(txtValorSalario.getText()));

    salario = pagamento.getSalario();

    if(cbIRRF.isSelected()){
        irrf = salario * 0.17;
        txtIRRF.setText(String.valueOf(irrf));
    }
    else txtIRRF.setText("");

    if(cbINSS.isSelected()){
        inss = salario * 0.05;
        txtINSS.setText(String.valueOf(inss));
    }
    else txtINSS.setText("");

    valorTotal = salario + irrf + inss;
    txtValorTotal.setText(String.valueOf(valorTotal));

}
```

O usuário digita um valor numérico qualquer referente ao salário do funcionário e pode clicar nas caixas de verificação (`JCheckBox`) referentes às contribuições incidentes. Se a caixa do IRRF estiver marcada, deve aparecer o valor do Imposto de Renda Retido na Fonte correspondente, isto é, 17% do valor do salário. Da mesma forma, se a caixa do INSS estiver marcada, deve aparecer o valor do INSS correspondente (5%).

Comment: Pode adicionar o código do que tentou fazer na pergunta?

Comment: @Articuno coloquei

Comment: Mas a sua questão é de como capturar o evento de seleção no `JCheckBox` para poder fazer algo ?

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar um evento ao seu checkbox, um actionPerformed é ideal, veja o exemplo a baixo.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("teste");
    JPanel painel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Me selecione");
    checkBox.addActionListener(((e) -> {
        if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
            field.setText("Voce clicou o Checkbox Parabens!");
        } else {
            field.setText("");
        }

    }));
    painel.add(checkBox);
    painel.add(field);
    frame.add(painel);
    frame.setSize(500, 50);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```